# HTTP Content-Type in ASP.Net SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, content-type

I have a problem with a Web Service Consumer written in ASP.NET. The error message is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Client found response content type of 'application/xml; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
```

The client is based on System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol. <del>We can't change the Content-Type given by the provider, this has to be 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.</del> Is there any way to change what Content-Type the SoapHttpClientProtocol expects? Unfortunately, we are *probably* limited to .NET 1.1.

Thanks!

**Update:** We found a way to change the Content-Type sent by the provider, and this solved the problem. I'd still be curious to know how to change the expectations of the consumer though.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

> Service Reference

for such Web Service not the

> Web Reference

in your .net client Application